# Field access and Memory Allocation for Objects in Java Polymorphism

Tags: java, memory, polymorphism, allocation

I have following sample code explaining sample Polymorphism concept - Overriding

```
    class Super
    {
        public int number = 1;
        public char superText='a';
        public String getColor()
        {
            return "red";
        }
    }

    class Sub extends Super
    {
        public int number = 2;
        public char subText='b';

        public String getColor()
        {
            return "blue";
        }
    }


    public class Sample2 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Super supersub = new Sub();
            System.out.println( supersub.getColor() + supersub.number + supersub.superText );
        }



    }
```

The Output is blue1.

**Question 1:**

The Method in derived class getColor() is overridden and Field of the Super class is displayed.

Can some one explain why number field in derived class is not called ? i.e., output is blue2

---

**Question 2:** **REGARDING MEMORY ALLOCATION**

for below object instantiation,

```
   Sub subobj = new Sub();
```

Memory for field 'number' is allocated in heap and the address of the Number variable
    is assigned to object reference, subobj.

consider below case,

```
Super supersub = new Sub();
```

**(a)** Here memory for variables, 'number and subText' in derived class 'Sub' is created and the address of the variables is placed in supersub Object

when i access,  supersub.subText i got error that subText cannot be resolved.

SO, PLEASE EXPLAIN **POINT (a)** described above i.e., Memory Allocation of Derive Class variables

Thanks,
Cyborgz

Comment: you should at least attempt to explain what you think the answers are...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question 1:
>
> The Method is derived class is displayed and Field of the Super class
>   is displayed.
>
> Can some one explain why number field in derived class is not called ?
>   i.e., output is blue2

Fields cannot be overridden. Even if two classes share a parent-child relationship, the fields belong to the class they were defined in, even if they share names with an inherited field. In other words, `number` in `Sub` is totally different field than `number` in `Super`.

> Question 2: 
>        Here memory for variables, 'number and subText' in derived class 'Sub' is created and the address of the variables is placed in
>   supersub Object 
>        when i access, supersub.subText i got error that subText cannot be resolved.

The object stored in `supersub` is of type `Sub`, but the compiler doesn't know that.

Because Java is a *statically typed* language, the compiler goes by the *declared* type (that is, the variable type) of the reference because, in most real-world cases, the *runtime* type (the one that's apparent in the `new` expression) isn't necessarily known at compile time. For example, you may have gotten this object from another method, or from two or three candidate methods, therefore the runtime type is unpredictable.

Storing the reference in a superclass variable means that you intend to use that object as `Super` for a while. The compiler, then, works on this perceived intention of yours. `Super` isn't guaranteed to only have instances of a runtime type of `Sub`, therefore it can't make the assumptions you expect.

That being said, storing the reference in one kind of variable or another does not modify the object. If you were to cast the object back to a variable of a type that actually knows about those members you're trying to access (in your case, the `Sub` type), you'll find that they're still there (and they retain their values).

Answer (score 2):

Fields in Java are not called and are never subject to dynamic dispatch/runtime polymorphism. In your case there are actually two separate fields that just happen to have the same name: `Super#number` and `Sub#number`. The `Sub` class inherits `Super#number` so it has **both**, and which one you access depends on the **static compile-time** type of the variable you access it through. That explains why `subobj` accesses one and `superobj` the other.

Answer (score 2):

> Can some one explain why number field in derived class is not called ?

That's because `fields` are not polymorphic. When accessing fields on a particular reference, you get access to the field defined in the reference type, and decision is not based on the actual object type.

> Memory for field 'number' is allocated in heap and the address of the
>   Number variable is assigned to object reference, subobj.

**No**, `number` is primitive type `int`, and primitives are not allocated on heap. They are stored on literal pool. Primitives, and Wrapper classes are two different things. Had you used `Integer` instead of `int`, then you would have created object on `Heap`, if the value was not in the range, that is cached by `Java` literal pool.

> supersub.subText i got error that subText cannot be resolved.

This can be infered from the explanation of your first doubt. Since field access are resolved based on reference type, and not on actual object type. So, clearly you can't access `subText` on a `Super` reference, since that field is not the part of that class, rather of the sub class.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, because you cannot override fields. The methods are the only things that can be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

You do not override class variables in Java: you hide them. Overriding is for instance methods.